# I want the Widget title to set below contant

Tags: plugins

The first image is taken from image widget.The second one is the view of the image. I want the title to set below the image only this widgets. How can I do it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the HTML structure or only the looks of that widget?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. copy widget files, rename the widget, change HTML output.
2. With css, set container element to `postion:relative`, title element `position:absolute` and move it with `bottom:0` and `left:0`..
3. Use javascript/jQuery to swap img and title element.

---

1 is the best solution.
2 & 3 are kinda hacky.

I can't give you any examples without an url.

Comment: i already create a custom widget function. but i don't understand how the title to set below the image. please send me custom HTML output code.

Comment: That's a bit reversed, it's better you share your code. Add it to your excisting question (edit it).

Comment: already share my custom widgets function.

Comment: Please do not include code as an image. Also, the code you provided is to create a sidebar, not the widget. We need the widget code. To be more precise, the extended `WP_Widget` class that creates the widget. That class holds all functions that create your widget.